# Piwik integrated on iframe redirect

Tags: php, html, matomo

So I have piwik integrated on an iframe on mylocalhost, I made the settings in `config.ini.php` in order for the embed to work

```
[General]
enable_framed_pages=1
```

And I tested like this

```
<iframe src="http://site/index.php?module=Login&action=logme&login=admin&password=myhash&idSite=1" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

It's working, but it'redirecting me to the subdomain where Piwik is hosted, I want to stay on that iframe, do you know a workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more details about your domains configuration and what Piwik version are you using? I just checked this setting between two vhosts on my local machine and this seems to be working fine.

Cheers !